# Can't run GPU_FFT in an infinite loop

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, gpu, fft, raspbian

I am currently trying to take FFT using GPU_FFT libraries provided with Pi. I've successfully taken FFT of the data. However, whenever I try this in a while(1) loop, somehow it takes FFT 1023 times and stops at 1024th. I've read about someone who faced with [exact same issue on Raspberry Pi official forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=91877&p=642341), but couldn't figure out how to fix mine.

The code below is function to compute FFT

```
    void computeFFT(float *Input,float *Output){

    struct GPU_FFT_COMPLEX *base;
    struct GPU_FFT *fft;
    int i;

    int ret = gpu_fft_prepare(mb,log2_N,GPU_FFT_FWD,1,&fft);
    base = fft->in;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        base[i].re =  Input[i]; base[i].im =0.0;

    gpu_fft_execute(fft);
    base = fft->out;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        Output[i]= base[i].re;

    gpu_fft_release(fft);
}
```

and this is my while(1) loop

```
    while (1){
    if (mb != 0)
        mb = mbox_open();

    adc1Value = a2d(adc1Channel);
    voltage1 = ((2.5/4096) * adc1Value);
    QueueGet(Queue);
    QueuePut(voltage1);

    OutData = computeFFT(Queue,OutData);
    printf("%f\n",OutData[0]); // Printing out signal value on 0Hz
}
mbox_close(mb);
free(OutData);
return 0;
```

I do believe problem is related to where I use mbox_open and close functions.

Things that I tried

- Changing Queue into new array with random number generated with rand().
- Changing location of mbox functions as suggested.
- Disabling a2d function
- Changing FFT length to 512, 2048, 4096.

Yet none of them was the solution.

Comment: Difficult to tell from a program fragment and somewhat vague description of the behavior. Still, if the program fails after a consistent number of iterations then I would advice you to begin pinpointing the cause by breaking into the loop at the final iteration and single-stepping in your debugger. Try replacing the individual pieces such as the IPC, ADC sampling and FFT computation with dummy replacements to narrow down the cause, and reopen a fresh mailbox on each iteration. Then revise the question with your findings unless you have already discovered the root cause.

Comment: @doynax I'm pretty sure problem is within FFT computing algorithm. For example this is the exact same problem that I encounter https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=91877&p=642341 .In this topic, they suggested user to include mbox_close which one user did not agree with. After that user that posted problem said it's solved by including mbox_close() in function itself. However whatever I've done so far, could not fix this. Every single time programs runs 1023 times and fails without giving any error at 1024th.

Comment: Shouldn't `if (mb != 0)` be `if (mb == 0)`? Also, you really should be checking the return value of your function calls (like `mbox_open`) for errors/failures. `mbox_open` will return `NULL` if it fails.

Comment: @Cornstalks As I remember, when mb = mbox_open() it returns 0 and when it's closed, it's NULL. As you said, I should not be checking mb and in fact I was not checking it, I've changed the code many times that's the last try that I made.